# How to set time for touch the cell in a tableview?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody i have a tableview ,when i click the cell it popups a view,its work fine for me,but my question is, i want to tap for 2 second to popup appear.that is ,if i tap the cell for 2 second then only the popup appers.Is that possible?How can i do this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.view addSubview:MainPopupView];
//MainPopView is the popup that i want to display after2 minit
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) a try. You can set the `minimumPressDuration` to set the time for the gesture to be recognized.

You can add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your table view cell and get the desired action.

**Update**
Please take a look at this previous SO question [How can I determine if a user has pressed on a UITableViewCell for 2 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314524/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-has-pressed-on-a-uitableviewcell-for-2-seconds)

Comment: i know the class refrence of longtapgesture,but how can i implement in the didselectrowatindexpath?thnks.

Comment: See of this previous SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924446/long-press-on-uitableview/3924965#3924965 gives you a starting point

Comment: i have this code and where to put my popup show code tot his code?-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:table];
    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    else
        NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
}